# The facts behind MSG type

Tags: c++, function, types, typedef, msg

I need some information on this type that is obviously type defined in the windows header.
I really do not wish to post code up for its really to much to ask of someone to look at.

I just need some information on the MSG type, i am using this with creating a window.

I know the functionality of the command but i would like a reliable link of documentation for reliable facts.

Bonus question:
When compiling an application does the compiler compile typedefs as their definitions or does the application itself reference that definition?

The first question is more important then the second. Thanks

Comment: Well, I think you should start with [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590(v=vs.85).aspx) about messages (which includes the MSG structure) from MS itself.

Comment: Second question: It's the compiler that understands typedefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need information about it? You fill the structure in one function, and then call some other functions with it in the message loop.

If you must know: [MSDN: MSG Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: To answer your question, i like to know everything i am writing. You can not truly call yourself a programmer if your inputting code that you have no idea of its ideal functionality. Thank you for your answer i couldn't find it.

Comment: @user2588062, it's "ideal functionality" means using it the way it was designed to be used in a message loop. That doesn't require looking inside the structure.